# Improving responsiveness of table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking to improve the responsiveness of my page based on the two layouts I've created.

Below are my query breakpoints:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 768px), screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)  {

}
```

My problem is to correct the issue I'm having when I resize my browser between widths of 1024 and 1224 particularly with my  is to look at ensure my calendar table .. I've explained my self in further details below.

For the calendar table could you attempt re-sizing the browser width to 1180px or just below this value (inspect element on chrome tells you the browser width) .. you will notice the calendar goes below the vertical menu bar .. at this width size I don't want this to happen .. i would like to have the calendar cells reduce in size

Any ideas are appreciated.

Here's my demo:

```css
/* Full width styling */

* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #363636;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}
h2 {
  line-height: 280%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h3 {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}
p {
  padding: 1%;
}
img {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
header {
  background-color: #3366FF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.90%;
}
#logo {
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 86px;
  background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 25px 20px 20px 0;
}
#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 86px;
  background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
}
section {
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
  text-align: center;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#genericlinkdecoration {
  color: #3366FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #808080;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
footer p,
footer h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
footer p a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul.social li {
  display: inline;
}
ul.social img {
  height: 50px;
}
footer.footerTwo {
  border-top: 1px solid #4D4350;
  background-color: #3366FF;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Media queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px),
screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    position: absolute;
  }
  header {
    position: absolute;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav {
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav ul,
  nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    right: 20px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: #363636;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #3366FF;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  section {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
.horizontalmenubar {
  margin-top: 86px;
  background: #33DD00;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

.horizontalmenubar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

.horizontalmenubar li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: 200px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/

.horizontalmenubar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #D6D6D6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/

.horizontalmenubar li:hover a {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #3366FF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

.horizontalmenubar li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

.horizontalmenubar li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
/* Style the <a> tag nested in sub-menus */

.horizontalmenubar li ul li a {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
/* Style the hovering of the <a> tag nested in sub-menus */

.horizontalmenubar li:hover ul li a {
  background: #D6D6D6;
  color: #000000;
}
/* Style the hovering of the <a> tag nested in sub-menus */

.horizontalmenubar li ul li a:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #3366FF;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

.horizontalmenubar ul li a:hover + .hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  background: #D6D6D6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/

.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

.horizontalmenubar input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles - horizontalmenubar  */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px),
screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  .horizontalmenubar ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  .horizontalmenubar li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  .horizontalmenubar ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
.maindiv {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFCC00;
}
/* LHS div */

.div_lhs_menu {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
/* Main menu */

.js-css-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
.js-css-menu,
.js-css-menu ul,
.js-css-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.js-css-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.js-css-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
}
.js-css-menu > li > a {
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.js-css-menu > li:hover > a {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #3366FF;
}
/* Dropdown */

.js-css-menu > li div {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: #D6D6D6;
}
.js-css-menu > li:hover div {
  display: block;
}
.js-css-menu > li div ul {
  float: none;
}
.js-css-menu > li div ul li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.js-css-menu > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94;
}
.js-css-menu.vertical > li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}
.js-css-menu.vertical > li div {
  width: 150px;
  top: 0;
  left: 181px;
  /* Adjust the left value according to the width of the vertical menu */
}
.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #407D94;
}
.js-css-menu.vertical > li div ul li a {
  color: #555;
}
/*Responsive Styles - .js-css-menu.vertical*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px),
screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* Vertical */
  .js-css-menu.vertical {
    width: 100%;
    /* Adjust the width of the vertical menu */
  }
}
/*  Generic table styling */

.overalldivcalendartable {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* Zebra striping */

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
th:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "Mon";
}
th:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: "Tue";
}
th:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: "Wed";
}
th:nth-of-type(4):before {
  content: "Thu";
}
th:nth-of-type(5):before {
  content: "Fri";
}
th:nth-of-type(6):before {
  content: "Sat";
}
th:nth-of-type(7):before {
  content: "Sun";
}
td {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
}
/*Responsive Styles - div_lhs_menu and table */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px),
screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .div_lhs_menu {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .overalldivcalendartable {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  td,
  th {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
  }
  th:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "M";
  }
  th:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: "T";
  }
  th:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: "W";
  }
  th:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: "T";
  }
  th:nth-of-type(5):before {
    content: "F";
  }
  th:nth-of-type(6):before {
    content: "S";
  }
  th:nth-of-type(7):before {
    content: "S";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>QWERTY</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/blueberryresponsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/dashboardresponsive.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#containerjoin">My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <!--  class="current" -->
        <li><a href="#containerjoin">Log Out</a>
        </li>
        <!--  class="current" -->
        <li><a href="#">Help and FAQs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="horizontalmenubar">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">MAIN MENU</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
      <!-- removed id="menu" -->

      <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a>
        <!-- <ul class="hidden">
     <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
    </ul>-->
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
        <!-- <ul class="hidden">
     <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
    </ul>-->
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
        <!-- <ul class="hidden">
     <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SUB MENU OPTION</a></li>
    </ul>-->
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">H MENU OPTION</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="maindiv">
    <div class="div_lhs_menu">

      <ul class="js-css-menu responsive vertical">
        <li><a href="#overalldivcalendartable">Calendar</a>
          <!--<div>

            <ul>
              <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
              <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div> -->

        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Dboard option 2</a>
          <!--<div>

            <ul>
              <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
              <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div> -->
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Dboard option 3</a>
          <!--<div>

            <ul>
              <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
              <li><b>Col 1</b></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- JS targets this div -->
    <div class="overalldivcalendartable">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td class="selected">17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>19</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>26</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <section>
      <h3>ABOUT US:</h3>

      <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..
        <br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..
        <br>
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3>LIKE, FOLLOW OR WATCH US:</h3>
      <ul class="social">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/youtube.png" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="contactus">
      <h3>CONTACT US:</h3>

      <p>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..
        <br>
        <br><b>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</b>
        <br>
        <br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..
        <br>qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty .. qwerty ..</p>
    </section>
  </footer>
  <footer class="footerTwo">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 | qwerty Ltd | All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tables aren't responsive by nature. Even limiting their width is reliant on their content. [Responsive Data Tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) will show you some of their ideas, but tables are horrible to try to do in mobile responsive designs. It takes planning for exactly what data should be shown in mobile view if at all. My basic go to is to not show it unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best best would probably be to use width percentages on `.overalldivcalendartable`. So at the breakpoint where the table slips below the side menu, set the width to 75%.

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1185px) {
    .overalldivcalendartable {
        width: 75%;
    }
}
```

Then when the other responsive features kick into play, and the table should drop down below the menu, you can then increase the width back to 100%.

```
@media screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .overalldivcalendartable {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Please see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Schybo/mp63rjf6/)

You could also have the width on the table and the side menu set at the start (page load) by setting `.div_lhs_menu` width to 25%, and then `.overalldivcalendartable` set to 74% so then you wouldn't have to reduce the width at some arbitrary point.

Comment: Thanks .. this works but I intend on generating my calendar using JS ... i dont know how this will behave

Comment: Using javascript to generate it should not affect anything as long as the correct classes are on the div when you dynamically create it. Post here though if something breaks.